# Prepare Integration Test test data only once for ALL Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing

Should an Integration Test Test_Method call its individual test data once or should I setup the test data for ALL Test_Methods in a Setup method which is called before every Test_Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if your tests are changing the values of the test data - because it could cause your subsequent tests to fail if value a is updated by test 1 to value b...and test 2 expects value b.

Otherwise, if your tests only read data and don't change it then you could setup the data once, using something like NUnits `[TestFixtureSetup]` attribute, rather than the individual tests `[SetUp]` attribute, which you should use if you need the data resetting each time.

Comment: yes every test method changes data BUT after a Test all data is removed in the TearDown method.

Comment: In that case then, just use [SetUp] to create the test data.